# How to create a SQL query to get sum of a particular column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to create to query using the data shown in the image below. I need to sum the `Data` field based on the `ID` column.

[image]

Expected Result:

[image]

I need to get distinct `ID` field and sum the `Data` column 
Note: `location` and `Trc` are the same for particular `ID`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for ID 30 you have 2 different commessa's but sum everything for ID 30. which commesa do you need in the result?

Comment: Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: No need of Commesa value. @Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregate function sum in data column

```
select ID,location,Trc,Commessa sum(data) From Table
Group by ID,location,Trc,Commessa
```

Comment: Id 30 have different commessa values.

Comment: This query will return 4 rows, using the sample data. (Two rows for id 30.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
Select ID,location,Commessa,Trc, sum(Data) as Data
from
YOUR_TABLE_NAME
group by ID, location, Commessa, Trc
```

Comment: Id 30 have different commessa values.

Comment: @jarlh location, Commessa, Trc are same for particular ID he noted this

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin but that is not what you see on his sample data shown in the image

Comment: This query will return 4 rows, using the sample data, two rows for id 30.

Comment: @Kevin that could be his type mistake

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin that's why I asked him the question which one he wants to see in his result...

Comment: I think that's just a typo. I answered according to the question he asked. He specifically mentioned "Sum Data column Note( location, Commessa, Trc are same for particular ID)"

Comment: @Kevin after seeing "location, Commessa, Trc are same for particular ID" this note, its normal to understand that is typo